# Disappearing Text in HTML page

Tags: html, css

I just started using jsFiddle to make this (https://jsfiddle.net/travism2006/tp2y5pvu/1/)

```css
body .main .leftAd {
  border: 4px red dashed;
  width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#main">Skip Links</a>
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Coding</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Web Tech</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Data Fun</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Robotics</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="leftAd">sss</div>
```

Can someone explain why the 'sss' disappears + the border not showing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<a href="#main">Skip Links</a>
    <header>
        <ul>
              ...
        </ul>
     <\header>
<div class="left-ad"><p>sss</p></div>
```

OR

```
<aside class="left-ad">sss</aside>
```

I would suggest you go back through your code because there are a lot of semantic issues that need to be addressed if you're trying to understand it better. What Vincent said may work, but it is not the best solution. Also the new semantic elements that are added to HTML5 cut down some of the code and make your code more understandable. It beats having to make divs and text elements over and over. Instead of using div elements you should use the header and  aside semantic elements which can be used for headers and advertisements respectively. You can float each with simple CSS like you have done. Lastly, you shouldn't name the class attributes left and right by themselves. That is very general and it makes your code harder for others to discern. I used .left-ad and .right-ad and it worked just fine. If you have any additional questions I'm here to help. It's essential that you understand these concepts to make your code easier to read, debug if need be later on, and makes you really understand the semantics behind what your writing.

**when I opened your fiddle, the HTML lacked a lot of content. Specifically, the sss that appears here but not in your js fiddle. When a div has no content in your case it collapses in on itself and that's why you see a flat red line because the top and bottom borders are lying on top of each other. In order to make additional space for the added sss container just add custom padding values etc.**

```
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: I am grateful for your answer and now my HTML is more readable as you pointed out.  Also, I took out my class for the 'aside' tag.  I just updated Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/travism2006/tp2y5pvu/3/).

Comment: How does this actually the answer of why the div disappears?

Answer (score 3):

I played around with the fiddle and found that my ad-blocker was adding 'display: none;' to the elements with the "Ad" substring in them.

Renaming the elements from 'leftAd' and 'rightAd' to 'left' and 'right' made them display as you'd expect.